# is there a way i can use the object list in jsp to get data into the dto?

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a member of my `CustomerDto` as

```
List<Services> serviceList;
```

and the Services is another Dto which contains following fields;

```
private int serviceId;
private String serviceName;
```

what I need to do is create a JSP that will take fill the customer DTO and also fill multiple services which will be set to serviceList which is a List.

The JSP page I am currently using contains the following code to get and show the services list. Currently what I am doing is displaying the text field to enter the service name and if the user wants to enter more services then he/her add text fields using '+' button. To get these values in DTO I am using a List which just holds the service name. In the database, I have a separate table for Services.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${countServiceName-1 }" >
    <c:set var="divName" value="my${i}Div" />
    <div style="margin-top: 5px" id="${divName }">
        <input type="text"name="serviceList" value="${customerRegistrationDto.serviceList[i] }" title="Service Name" maxlength="200" style="width:400px;vertical-align:middle;"/>
        <a href="javascript:removeInputBox('${divName }')" ><img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/common/x.png" />" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-left: 2px"/></a>
    </div> 
</c:forEach>
```

Is There anyway I can achieve this? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Or please let me know if i can achieve this without using List<Object>

Comment: Show us the JSP code you have so far... its much easier to add to your existing code than write an example from scratch. And take a look at the FAQ for hints on how to write a "good" SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should use AutoPopulatingList, [example1](http://java-sandbox.cloudfoundry.com/autopopulatinglist) & [example2](http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=12). This will require change in MyRequest entity.

Comment: Thank You @Jigar Parekh, I will go through the examples you provided and try to implement in my case and let you know if it works. Thanks again for your help.. :)

Comment: I am trying to implement the AutoPopulatingList for the above situation. I searched for the AutoPopulatingList examples to find out how to map the AutoPopulatingList member of my Dto, but gives invalid property error for <spring:bind path="customerRegistrationDto.serviceDtoList[0].serviceName"></spring:bind> can you elaborate on how to map this?